# HP 1210 scan button does nothing

Tags: windows-xp, printing

I have an HP 1210 all-in-one nightmare of a printer which has decided not to listen to the scan button anymore.  I've dug into it, and see in the properties of the scanner in Windows XP that it says "No applications are registered for this event" under what to do when the Scan button is pressed.  I've tried re-installing the HP software, didn't help.  Updated the drivers off the website, and downgraded them to the ones on the CD, neither had an effect.

Is there any way to tell Windows to just open the Scan/Cammera wizard when I press the Scan button on the printer?

Windows XP SP3, if that matters.

Comment: What kind of a cable are using to connect it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Download and install the button handler update for use in Windows XP.
    NOTE:   Read the entire instructions in Solution 2 carefully before following the link in Step 1 to find the correct update for the scanner in use.

    Go to the HP Support and Driver page .
    In the I want to: section, select download drivers and software , type the model of the scanner in use in the For: box, and then click the double arrows to advance to the next page.
    Click Windows XP . A Software and Drivers download page opens.
    Find and double-click the button handler update to go to the download page.
    Click Download Now . A download window opens.
    Click Save . The software begins downloading to the selected location. Make a note of the location of the folder and the file name so that it can be found after downloading.
    Navigate to the location where the file was saved during the download and double-click it. The installation program starts.
    Follow the instructions on the computer screen to complete the installation of the Windows XP button handler update software.
```

Check the troubleshooting steps on HP Support. 
[HP Scanjet Scanners - Scanner Front Panel Buttons Do Not Work in Windows XP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01280439&lang=en&cc=us&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=73500&prodTypeId=15179)

Comment: The HP support link is dead at this point and doesn't seem to exist in an archive anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check for *HP services* in **services.msc** and in *startup services/process* with **msconfig**, they have to be all enabled.

But its looks like registry problem, try to reinstall the drivers and utility again

---- EDIT -----

"No applications are registered for this event" tells that the button work but there is no application to intercept its call. so, the first thing i will do is to set the utility in question or any image editing software as the default.  look if you can find it in **control panel >> set default program** and reassign it to (all file types and protocols)

Comment: Looked at `msconfig`, and the only things disabled were Quicktime, MS Office, or Adobe related.  As for the services, the only relevant thing I see in there is a HID service which isn't starting.  I've already done an uninstall, reboot, and reinstall of the drivers and software.

Comment: have you reinstalled the "HP PSC software" ? if you can located the setting where you can define the action for the "Scan key" press the to refresh that one, there some instruction on your manual http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpu05102.pdf hope that can lead you to a solution ...

Comment: Yes, I have.  It still doesn't work, even in Windows 7.  I think it's just broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any desired program as a scanner button handler using the registry editor. Navigate to this key:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\StillImage\Registered Applications`

Under this key, add a string value with the Name = `<Program name>` and Value = `<Program path`>. The path can include arguments, with %1 and %2 passing information about which scanner triggered the event *(I don`t recall what exactly these parameters contain)*.

After adding your custom handler, go into the scanner properties and you new handler will be listed there.